# data normalization which have lots of zero values

Tags: r, normalization

My data have ratio type and count type variables and they have lots of zeros.

Since they are skewed to right, I want to normalize the data.

I'e tried square root transformation and log transformation and the results are shown below.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, because of the zeros, transformation doesn't normalize the data.

I want to know the transformation method to this kind of data.

Comment: It's extremely rare that you need to normalize data. If you have (possibly zero-inflated) count or ratio data, you should use methods designed for such data for your statistical analyses instead of trying to transform the data.

Comment: Also your scales are not that different which also makes normalization a bit redundant

Comment: It's a simple but also fundamental principle that a spike in the original data remains a spike after transformation. In short, not only is getting much closer to normal not likely to be needed, it is also likely to be impossible for several of thee variables. Also, log of zero is undefined and log of negative values not usefully defined statistically, so it's not clear how you got round that.

Comment: In fact your code does explain what you did, namely take logs of value $+ 10^{-7}$. But that's not a gentle modification to logarithms at all: it makes the distribution worse as zeros became a spike of outliers ($-7$ with base 10. etc.)